# How do Randomforests train the model

Tags: random-forest

Everywhere I read about RF, Out of bag samples are used to evaluate the performance of a random forest. But what exactly will happen with this evaluation? Reading the algorythm it just says to repeat for each tree the recursive node splitting. And that trees are independent. So what exactly is there to train and minimize?

Answer (score 0):

In RF, the OOB validation set can be used to remove redundant features in your model. Potential redundant features can be removed one by one from each tree and then you can check if the accuracy of the OOB validation set actually improves.

So you first generate your trees, then optimize them individually removing redundant features and then combine them together the RF way (letting them vote on incoming instances). If the trees are uncorrelated they will nullify the errors of each particular tree.

Check the **Removing redundant features** section in this [post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/interpret-random-forest-model-machine-learning-programmers/)

Comment: So is reducing the features you may select the only thing, depth or other feature remains the same? Are you still using the old trees that used them, as I understood nothing is deleted or pruned?